# Radio buttons show image on check

Tags: jquery, css

I have some radio buttons in which when one is checked, a tick appears beside the radio button and the rest are not checked.

the radio button html and css is as below

```
<input type="radio" name="InputName" value="ValueA" >

input[type="radio"]:checked + .icon {
background-image: url("../img/glyphicons-halflings.png");
}
```

However, i am using jquery as well to change the checked status of one of the radio buttons but I am unable to change it. My jquery is as below

```
$('[name="InputName" value="ValueA"]').attr('checked',true);
```

Any solutions? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You should call like this:

```
$('[name="InputName"]').attr('checked',true);
```

Answer (score 0):

use [`prop()`](http://api.jquery.com/prop/) .you can just do

```
 $('input[value="ValueA"]').prop('checked',true);
```

if your value is unique...

**OR**

this

```
$('input[name="InputName"][value="ValueA"]').prop('checked',true);
```

Answer (score 0):

You should try this, instead of `.attr('checked',true)` try `.attr('checked','checked')`

```
$('[name="InputName"][value="ValueA"]').attr('checked','checked');
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead doing this:

```
$('[name="InputName" value="ValueA"]').attr('checked',true);
```

Do this:

```
$(':radio:checked').addClass('icon');
```

---

[See a demo](http://jsfiddle.net/BFLvV/) of the below pasted code:

```
$(':radio').change(function () {
   $(':radio').removeClass('icon');
   $(':checked').addClass('icon');
});
```

---

`radios` are made for this `if you want to select only one option in a radio list` for this `just group them with same name` then only one will be get selected.

like this:

```
<input type="radio" name="InputName" value="ValueA">
<input type="radio" name="InputName" value="ValueB">
<input type="radio" name="InputName" value="ValueC">
```